# How does Sage's "var" work?

Tags: python, module, global, cython, sage

In trying to create a Python function similar to [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/)'s `var()` or `function()`, I've encountered an apparently not-so-trivial problem in Python. Essentially, calling `var('x')` in Sage not only returns a Sage symbolic expression, but does the equivalent of `x = SR.var('x')`, i.e. it assigns the expression object to a variable in the current global namespace (the namespace of the calling module).

My question is, how the heck does it do that? If I do something like this:

in `B.py`:

```
def func():
    globals()['x'] = something
```

in `A.py`

```
from B import func
func()
```

I can only affect the variables in module `B`'s global namespace, not the calling module `A`'s global namespace.

Yet, the file `var.pyx` distributed with my version of Sage looks like this:

```
...

def var(*args, **kwds):
    if len(args)==1:
        name = args[0]
    else:
        name = args
    G = globals()  # this is the reason the code must be in Cython.
    if 'ns' in kwds:
        # ...
        # not relevant
    v = SR.var(name, **kwds)
    if isinstance(v, tuple):
        for x in v:
            G[repr(x)] = x
    else:
        G[repr(v)] = v
    return v

...
```

In particular, the comment about Cython seems intriguing. I don't know much about Cython, so maybe that's my problem. If this is some special aspect of Cython, how would one go about replicating this function in "regular Python"/CPython?

PS: Yes, I realize that in general, such behavior is a bad idea. I'm mainly asking out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation was found in [https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sage-devel/*J*-kDHlnT4/discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sage-devel/_J_-kDHlnT4/discussion)

I quote Volker Braun:

> In src/setup.py we set

```
Cython.Compiler.Options.old_style_globals = True
```

> which causes Cython to fall back to the old behavior.

Comment: Ah, so there's a compiler flag to get the behavior from Cython < 0.15.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Cython 1.5's changelog](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/ReleaseNotes-0.15), we can see that

> globals() now returns a read-only dict of the Cython module's globals, rather than the globals of the first non-Cython module in the stack

Therefore this is a trick that only works on really old Cython compilers.

You can use this code to emulate it:

```
import inspect

def run():
    outer_frame = inspect.stack()[1][0]
    outer_frame_locals = inspect.getargvalues(outer_frame).locals

    outer_frame_locals["new_variable"] = "I am new"
```

although note that it is *very* implementation-defined.

Comment: Ah, that's very interesting, but it would seem strange to me if Sage used such an old version of Cython. Is there any way to find out the actual version they use? I haven't had much luck searching.

Comment: That's not correct. Sage updated to Cython 0.15 more than two years ago http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/11761 and the global trick is still in use https://github.com/sagemath/sagelib/blob/master/sage/calculus/var.pyx. On "Sage Version 5.10, Release Date: 2013-06-17" we used "Cython version 0.19.1"

Comment: There is a plan to upgrade to Cython 0.20 in Sage 6.2 http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/15755

Comment: @hivert Thank you. I'm afraid, though, that I'm probably not going to download an old Cython version just to test this. I've tested a much distilled version in Cython 0.20 and nothing happens so I stick by what I said in a *general* sense as a good possibility.

Comment: I thought it would be strange if Sage used an old version of Cython just for this. How _does_ it work, though, if Cython's `globals()` is the same as CPython's?

Comment: Cython probably just traversed the stack (the thing returned from `inspect.stack()`) upwards until it met a non-Cython module.

Comment: No, I mean that considering that Sage doesn't use a Cython version < 1.5, the original question still stands, i.e. how does the `var` function work, since Cython was changed to return the module's globals?